# Show text for Zend_PDF annotation

Tags: php, zend-framework, pdf, zend-pdf

I am trying to create the table of contents of already existing file using zend_pdf.

I am able to place the bookmarks but the text of the annotation is not getting displayed,though anchors are at there place .

$pages is the pages of the existing pdf file .

```
foreach ($pages as $pageNo => $page) {
    $newPage = $extractor->clonePage($page);
    $newPdf->pages[] = $newPage;
    $destination[$x] = Zend_Pdf_Destination_Fit::create($newPage);
    $target = Zend_Pdf_Action_GoTo::create($destination[$x]);      
    $annotation = Zend_Pdf_Annotation_Link :: create( $x1, $y1, $x2, $y2, $target );
    $annotation->setText('Annotate'.$x);
    $newPdf->pages[0]->attachAnnotation( $annotation );
    $newPdf->setNamedDestination('page_'.$x, $destination[$x]);    
    $newPdf->outlines[0]->childOutlines[] = Zend_Pdf_Outline::create('Page '.$x, $newPdf->getNamedDestination('page_'.$x)); 
    $x++;
  }
```

Attatched image shows what I am getting [image]

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong or what am I missing out ?